# How to add money to paypal account using API

Tags: paypal

I am looking for a way to add money to PayPal account using the API. We are making a website and using [PayPal Payout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/), which requires only using funds in the [PayPal account balance](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/standard/#:%7E:text=Sufficient%20funds%20in%20your%20PayPal%20business%20account). We want to automate adding money to the account balance and then making payouts to vendors. I have reviewed the [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/current-resources/) and could not figure out how to "add money" to the PayPal account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method to automate "adding money" to a PayPal account.

Comment: maybe in the future. thanks